# role "SYSTEM" does not exist in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I created a function in dbname "migrate" to store values from another dbname called "Fulfil.1.9.1" 
while executing function i'm getting error like this

> role "SYSTEM" does not exist

```
insert into ns_fw_theme(theme_id, theme_name)
select theme_id,
       theme_name
from dblink('dbname=Fulfil_1.9.1','select theme_id,
                                   theme_name from ns_fw_theme')
  AS t1(theme_id character varying(100), theme_name character varying(100));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Can you post a [mcve]? A Google Search normally can help with these sorts of problems.

Comment: Show us the code of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from dblink('host=localhost user=postgres password=admin dbname=Fulfil_1.9.1','..);